# Django flatpages: sort list

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
<ul>
{% for page in flatpages %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The code above will render a simple unordered list containing flatpages. I would like to sort them using the "index" property of each flatpage, instead of alphabetically by the "url" property (as it is done by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to write sort filter , or try to use

[dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std%3atemplatefilter-dictsort)

Or write django assignment tag.

Comment: Dictsort it is!
{% for page in flatpages|dictsort:"id" %}

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't (*should not*) change the core model of flatpages you *can* inherit it:

```
CustomFlatpage(Flatpage)
    # Possible extra fields, add methods or your own object manager
    class Meta:
         ordering = ['somefield']
```

If you want a simplified approach, could just write a templatetag that (re)sorts your queryset. This might cause some overhead but unless your site is high traffic or contains thousands of flatpages this should just be fine.

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
<ul>
{% for page in flatpages|your_pre_iteration_shuffle %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```